# net/http server: too many open files error

Tags: go

I'm trying to develop a simple job queue server with some worker that query it but I encountered a problem with my net/http server. I'm surely doing something bad but after ~3 minutes my server start displaying :

> http: Accept error: accept tcp [::]:4200: accept4: too many open files; retrying in 1s

For information it receive 10 request per second in my test case.

Here's two files to reproduce this error :

```
// server.go
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/get", func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        http.Error(rw, "Try again", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":4200", nil)
}

// worker.go
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    for {
        res, _ := http.Get("http://localhost:4200/get")
        defer res.Body.Close()

        if res.StatusCode == http.StatusInternalServerError {
            time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
            continue
        }

        return
    }
}
```

I already done some search about this error and I found some interesting response but none of these fixed my issue.

The first response I saw was to correctly close the Body in the http.Get response, as you can see I did it.

The second response was to change the file descriptor ulimit of my system but as I will not control where my app will run I prefer to not use this solution (But for information it's set at 1024 on my system)

Can someone explain me why this problem happen and how I can fix it in my code ?

Thanks a lot for your time

EDIT :
[image: Asked by comment]

EDIT 2 : In comment Martin says that I'm not closing the Body, I tried to close it (without defer so) and it fixed the issue. Thanks Martin ! I was thinking that continue will execute my defer, I was wrong.

Comment: if you're on linux, use `ps aux | grep {program-name}` to get your process ID and then `ls -l /proc/{process-id}/fd`to see open files when this error occurs. Add the output to your question. Thank you

Comment: this can help https://ttboj.wordpress.com/2015/07/27/golang-parallelism-issues-causing-too-many-open-files-error/

Comment: I believe that you anyway should update system properties.
Try this:
`echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p`

Comment: Your defer res.Body.Close() is queuing up all resource freeing until your worker main() returns. Explicitly call `res.Body.Close()` immediately after checking `http.Get` error and see if it behaves better.

Comment: Yes, Martin is correct: You **never** close any Request.Body.

Comment: You're right Martin ! Thanks for you help. Now I know that continue will not execute defer in a loop.

Comment: @Volker I'm trying to fix a similar issue for a friend of mine and in his case he's just using `httputil.ReverseProxy` so it doesn't have much control and as far as I can tell he's not reading from the request body directly (and the director function sets `req.Close = true`). I can't find any missing `Close()` call in his case, any ideas?

Comment: Even if you're handling connections closing properly, I believe you can get to this state with lots of traffic, or malicious clients holding on to the connections. So if you expose your Go server to the internet, don't forget to set timeouts as well:
https://blog.cloudflare.com/exposing-go-on-the-internet/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Martin say in comment I don't really closed the Body after the Get request. I used `defer res.Body.Close()` but it's not executed since I'm staying in the for loop. So `continue` dont't trigger `defer`

Answer (score 28):

I found a [post](https://medium.com/@nate510/don-t-use-go-s-default-http-client-4804cb19f779) explaining the root problem in a lot more detail.
Nathan Smith even explains how to control timeouts on the TCP level, if needed.
Below is a summary of everything I could find on this particular problem, as well as the best practices to avoid this problem in future.

### Problem

When a response is received regardless of whether response-body is required or not, the connection is kept alive until the response-body stream is closed. So, as mentioned in this thread, always close the response-body. Even if you do not need to use/read the body content:

```
func Ping(url string) (bool) {
    // simple GET request on given URL
    res, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        // if unable to GET given URL, then ping must fail
        return false
    }

    // always close the response-body, even if content is not required
    defer res.Body.Close()

    // is the page status okay?
    return res.StatusCode == http.StatusOK
}
```

### Best Practice

As mentioned by Nathan Smith never use the `http.DefaultClient` in production systems, this includes calls like `http.Get` as it uses `http.DefaultClient` at its base.

*Another reason to avoid `http.DefaultClient` is that it is a Singleton (package level variable), meaning that the garbage collector will not try to clean it up, which will leave idling subsequent streams/sockets alive.*

Instead create your own instance of `http.Client` and remember to always specify a sane `Timeout`:

```
func Ping(url string) (bool) {
    // create a new instance of http client struct, with a timeout of 2sec
    client := http.Client{ Timeout: time.Second * 2 }

    // simple GET request on given URL
    res, err := client.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        // if unable to GET given URL, then ping must fail
        return false
    }

    // always close the response-body, even if content is not required
    defer res.Body.Close()

    // is the page status okay?
    return res.StatusCode == http.StatusOK
}
```

### Safety Net

The safety net is for that newbie on the team, who does not know the shortfalls of `http.DefaultClient` usage. Or even that very useful, but not so active, open-source library that is still riddled with `http.DefaultClient` calls.

Since `http.DefaultClient` is a Singleton we can easily change the `Timeout` setting, just to ensure that legacy code does not cause idle connections to remain open.

I find it best to set this on the `package main` file in the `init` function:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func init() {
    /*
    Safety net for 'too many open files' issue on legacy code.
    Set a sane timeout duration for the http.DefaultClient, to ensure idle connections are terminated.
    Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37454236/net-http-server-too-many-open-files-error
    */
    http.DefaultClient.Timeout = time.Minute * 10
}
```

Comment: Default timeout to 10 Minutes is OK? Maybe 10 seconds?

Answer (score 2):

Please note that in some cases the setting in /etc/sysctl.conf 
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle       = 1

Could cause this error because TCP connections remain open.

Answer (score 2):

A temporary solution, just increase the number of open files:

```
ulimit -Sn 10000
```